# Flickering mouseover on image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm maintaining a legacy site and on this site there is a weird mouseover problem. It does not happens in IE, but it does in Chrome. I tried to see what the problem is, but I can't find it. It looks like the expand image is also reacting on the mouseover image. This is the url. It happens when you hover over an image and then hoover over the +.

http://www.moviq.nl/zonz-schaduwdoeken-zonnezeilen

Comment: If you also notice, it ghost the + near the top of the webpage no matter what the +. Can you show us your [+] hover css/javascript?

Comment: Can you show us the startAssetButtons function code?

Comment: Just type 'startAssetButtons' and 'endAssetButtons' in the console to see the code. It's minified but it's easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem at hand here is that when you hover the + sign, the  image hover event  gets lost, so the browser keeps changing from hover to non-hover status.
This is due to some weird things going on with your code... I would suggest that you make some changes to keep the code more simple and easy to interpret, and of course, also solving your problem:

The script that you have to the **onmouseover** and **onmouseout** events:

```
function endAssetButtons(el) {
  if (!Spif.isIE||!Spif.isIE7) {
    el.parentNode.style.position="";
    el.parentNode.style.overflow="";
  }
}
function startAssetButtons(el,id) {
  if (!Spif.isIE||!Spif.isIE7) {
    el.parentNode.style.position="relative";
    el.parentNode.style.overflow="hidden";
  }
}
```

is adding and removing some CSS to the image wrapper (div).
This is wrong and should be removed, since the CSS position:relative and the overflow:hidden should always be present to allow the + sign to always be absolutely positioned relatively to the image wrapper div.

**So, this css should be available to all browsers all the time:**

```
.contentAsset {
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

*content.css (Line 300)*

*This allows all browsers to deal with the + sign equally and keeping it hidden until the animation gets triggered.*

---

**Additionally, the css for the + sign should be changed into:**

```
.contentAssetButton {
    text-indent:-9999px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    display: block;
}
```

*content.css (Line 334)*

*This allows the + sign to have a more button alike style and be better recognized by all browsers.*

At the very least this should point you into the right direction!

Are here it is, [the Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/cMfk7/)

Comment: You are the BEST! Damn I would not be able to do this myself, css is not my thing. This code was already in the system so that made it even harder for me to figure it out. In my staging environment it is working 100% now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right + click (control + click on Mac) and Inspect Element, then mouseover very slowly.

The script for that + is adding a style that messes with the position of the image and causes your + to move out from under your cursor. If you go slowly you'll pinpoint the moment it happens.

over:

```
<div class="contentAsset contentAsset-hover contentAsset-hover-delayOff_500 
contentAsset-large contentAssetLast" style="position: relative; overflow-x: 
hidden; overflow-y: hidden; " id="qid_15">
```

out:

```
<div class="contentAsset contentAsset-hover contentAsset-hover-delayOff_500 
contentAsset-large contentAssetLast" style="" id="qid_15">
```

You might also look at the Console, lots of errors.

Answer (score 0):

try defining the height rather than attempting to define it with padding although that doesnt seem to change anything inside chromes editor.

I assume you're using the morph attribute to target some js somewhere? If so can you provide the js please.

Alternatively you could use just CSS3; http://ice.im/animatedlink/

I just made that for you, it couldn't be simpler your HTML is just:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->    
<div class="image"><a href="#"></a><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
```

Just change the class to whatever you'd like